# Show that $f(x)=0$ if there is zero arbitrarily close to $0$ for $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, rolles-theorem

Suppose that,

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$

converges on $(-R,R)$ for some $R>0$. If we let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $(-R,R)$ with $x_n\ne 0$ but $\lim x_n=0$. If $f(x_n)=0$ for all $n\in N$, I need to show that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in (-R,R)$.

My thinking is that I could use Rolle's Theorem. This theorem states that if we let $f$ be continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$. So if $f(a)=f(b)$ then there is at lest one point $c$ in $(a,b)$ where $f'(c)=0$

Can I use this logic? and if so how?

Comment: Not really, no. You're going to need to the fact that the power series converges. Differentiability of $f$, even infinite differentiability of $f$, is not sufficient to prove the statement.

Comment: Yes, Rolle's Theorem is a good start. But it can also be applied to $f^\prime$, $f^{\prime\prime}$, ... Then consider the Taylor series at $x=0$.

Comment: @quasi how would I do that?

Comment: @user905: Can you prove that $f(0)=0$?

Comment: A power series is uniformly convergent on compact intervals of the interval of convergence.  And in fact, they are continuous on the interval of convergence. Rolle's is not a way to proceed here.

Comment: @user905: You _do_ know that$f$ is infinitely differentiable on the interval $(-R,R)$, right? Hence, $f$ and all its derivatives are continuously differentiable on $(-R,R)$.

Comment: @quasi yes I can see that

Comment: @So why is $f(0) = 0$?

Comment: would it have something to do with the radius of convergence?

Comment: Indirectly, yes. Focus on continuity.

Comment: ah well I am not quite sure then

Comment: $f$ is continuous on $(-R,R)$, so in particular, $f$ is continuous at $x=0$. Now consider the sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$.

Comment: okay where do I go from there? if you could submit a answer, thanks anyways for your help

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous $x=0$, $x_n \to 0$, as $n \to \infty$ implies $f(x_n) \to f(0)$ as $n \to \infty$. Hence $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Then use Rolle's Theorem (again and again), and apply the same logic to $f^\prime$, $f^{\prime\prime}$, ... to show that $f$ and all its derivatives have a zero at $x=0$. Finally, use the fact that since $f$ is representable by a power series centered at $x=0$ on $(-R,R)$, that power series must be the same as the Taylor series for $f$ at $x=0$.

Comment: The rest is up to you -- good luck.

Comment: okay thanks for your tips

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is not identically zero, there must be some minimal $N$ such that $a_N\neq0$. This implies
$$f(x)=x^N\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+N}x^n.$$
In particular, we have $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^N}=a_N$. Since $x_k\neq0$ and $f(x_k)=0$, this implies
$$0=\frac{f(x_k)}{x_k^N}\to a_N\qquad\text{as }k\to\infty,$$
that is, $a_N=0$ which is a contradiction. This completes the proof.

Comment: this completes the proof? seems easier than attempting rolles theorem

Comment: It is indeed easier. As a couple of people in the comments said, Rolle's is not really appropriate here (as the other answer demonstrates, it works fine, but is not particularly elegant). The reason for that is this is really a question in complex analysis, so whatever you do should work in that case too and hence not rely on real calculus techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Notation: $f^{(j)}$ denotes the $j$th derivative of $f$, with $f^{(0)}=f$.

(I). Suppose $\{n:x_n>0\}$ is infinite. Take a strictly decreasing positive sub-sequence $(y_{0,n})_n$ of $(x_n)_n$.

Let $S(j)$ be the sentence: There exists a strictly decreasing sequence $(y_{j,n})_n$ in $(0,R)$, converging to $0,$ with $f^{(j)}(y_{j,n})=0$ for all $n.$

We have $S(0).$

If $S(j)$ then  by Rolle's Theorem, for each $n$ there exists $y_{j+1,n}\in (y_{j,n+1},y_{j,n})$ with $f^{(j+1)}(y_{j+1,n})=0.$ So $S(j)\implies S(j+1).$

So by induction on $j$ we have $S(j)$ for all $j\geq 0.$

Each $f^{(j)}$ is differentiable and therefore continuous, so for each $j$ we have $$j!a_j=f^{(j)}(0)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f^{(j)}(y_{j,n})=\lim_{n\to \infty}0=0.$$

(II). If $\{n:x_n>0\}$ is finite then $\{n:x_n<0\}$ is infinite and we can take a strictly increasing negative sub-sequence $(y_{0,n})_n$ of $(x_n)_n$ and proceed simiarly to the method of (I)...... Alternatively, we can let $g(x)=f(-x)$ and apply (I) to $g,$ and the last line is $(-1)^j\cdot j!a_j=0$.